# How do I make my scrolling work properly?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native

I am making a react native project with my android phone connected to my laptop.

**Problem:**

When I swipe on the right side of my phone screen the page scrolls. But when I swipe on the center or left side of my phone screen the page does not scroll.

I am also getting a warning in my console

```
VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.
```

I am not able to understand this warning. What is "orientation"?

This is my code:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from "react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { Block, Text, Button, Header } from "../../components";
import { ThemeProvider, Card } from "react-native-elements";
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, Modal, Image, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { typography, colors, spacing } from 'theme';
import { buttonStyles } from '../../theme/components/buttonStyles';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import users from './users.js';

export const SuperAdminScreensOrganizationDetailsScreen: FunctionComponent<{}> = observer(props => {

return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Header title="Organizations" navigation={props.navigation} />
            <ScrollView>
                <Block mb={spacing.huge}>
                    <Card>
                        <Block row space="between">
                            <Block>
                                <Text preset="subheader" >Organization 1</Text>
                                <Text preset="secondary">Expiration Date: 03-08-2019</Text>
                            </Block>
                            <Block row>
                                <Icon name="edit" size={spacing.large} />
                                <Text ml={spacing.tiny} preset="bold">
                                    Edit
                                </Text>
                            </Block>
                        </Block>
                        <Block row space="between">
                            <Block bottom left>
                                <Text preset="smallBold">
                                    Prateek Kolhi
                                </Text>
                                <Text preset="fieldLabel">+1 654 893 8098</Text>
                            </Block>
                            <Block>
                                <Block row right bottom>
                                    <ThemeProvider theme={buttonStyles}>
                                        <Button
                                            title="Add User"
                                            buttonStyle={{
                                                width: typography.smallButtonWidth,
                                                height: typography.smallButtonHeight
                                            }}
                                            titleStyle={{
                                                fontSize: typography.smallButtonFontSize,
                                                marginHorizontal: typography.smallButtonmx
                                            }}
                                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddNewUser')}
                                        />
                                    </ThemeProvider>
                                    <Block mx={spacing.tiny}></Block>
                                    <ThemeProvider theme={buttonStyles}>
                                        <Button
                                            title="Delete"
                                            buttonStyle={{
                                                width: typography.smallButtonWidth,
                                                height: typography.smallButtonHeight,
                                                backgroundColor: colors.cancelButtonBackground,
                                                borderWidth: typography.buttonBorderWidth,
                                                borderColor: colors.cancelButtonBorder
                                            }}
                                            titleStyle={{
                                                fontSize: typography.smallButtonFontSize,
                                                marginHorizontal: typography.smallButtonmx,
                                                color: colors.titleColor
                                            }}
                                            onPress={openModal}
                                        />
                                    </ThemeProvider>
                                </Block>
                                <Block bottom right>
                                    <Text preset="fieldLabel">root@organization.com</Text>
                                </Block>
                            </Block>
                        </Block>
                        <Text
                            mt={spacing.tiny}
                            pa={spacing.tiny}
                            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.totalMembers }}
                            mx={-spacing.medium}
                            mb={-spacing.medium}
                            pl={spacing.medium}
                        >
                            Total Members: {users.length}
                        </Text>
                        <FlatList
                            style={{ marginHorizontal: -spacing.medium }}
                            contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: spacing.medium }}
                            data={users}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                <Card
                                    containerStyle={styles.userCards}
                                >
                                    <Block row space="between" style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                        <Block row>
                                            <Block>
                                                <Image
                                                    source={item.src}
                                                    style={{ height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 25 }}
                                                />
                                            </Block>
                                            <Block ml={spacing.small} style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                                                <Text preset="smallBold">{item.firstName} {item.lastName}</Text>
                                                <Text preset="secondary">{item.role}</Text>
                                            </Block>
                                        </Block>
                                        <Block>
                                            <ThemeProvider theme={buttonStyles}>
                                                <Button
                                                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddNewUser')}
                                                    title="Edit Role"
                                                    buttonStyle={{
                                                        width: typography.smallButtonWidth,
                                                        height: typography.smallButtonHeight
                                                    }}
                                                    titleStyle={{
                                                        fontSize: typography.smallButtonFontSize,
                                                        marginHorizontal: typography.smallButtonmx
                                                    }}
                                                />
                                            </ThemeProvider>
                                        </Block>
                                    </Block>
                                </Card>
                            )}
                        />
                    </Card>
                </Block>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
});
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: could you upload this screen to an expo snack or code sandbox? Also, the warning is because you are using a FlatList inside a ScrollView, which is bad because you loose the optimization for the FlatList.

Answer (score 0):

FlatList and ScrollView shares the same logic, whenever you use FlatList inside ScrollView it is duplicated to solve this issue you can remove FlatList and you can use map like this:

```
  {users.map((item, index) => {
        ...your logic
    }}
```

Hope this helps!